# How can I send a message to a Telegram user?

Tags: android, telegram

my partner and I are creating an app to send S.O.S messages, and our intention is just clicking a button send directly a message requesting help. Is there any posibility to do this? We have searched for a lot of information, but we haven't found anything

Answer (score 0):

I think that your idea can come to real life implementing **Telegram API**. Telegram offers two kinds of APIs for developers:

**Bot API:** To easily create programs that use Telegram messages for an interface

**Telegram API:**  To build your own customized Telegram clients. You are welcome to use both APIs free of charge.  It is 100% open for all developers who wish to create Telegram applications on our platform.

With the information provided the second one could be the proper for you but if you can specify a little more would be fantastic.

[Official Telegram documentation](https://core.telegram.org/)

Comment: Yes, our app will have 3 buttons, one button to send directly a message by sms (done), the second button to send a custom message to a Whatsapp user (done), and the last button is to send directly a message to a Telegram user.